# How to connect between IBM Watson Assisstant and IBM Watson Discovery?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation, watson-discovery

I am using IBM Watson Assisstant to create a chatbot, and created a Watson Discovery collection too in the project.
I need help in that how the dialogs works to take a response from the Discovery collection when an intent along with the entities are detected in the try section.

- in the response section we have to define something or there is something else similar like text response
- is the discovery response is only available in the app on which we work

Comment: Check out this blog which has links to resources for combining Watson Assistant and Discovery. It is building a news bot https://blog.4loeser.net/2018/11/ibm-cloud-5-minute-barebone-news-chatbot.html It uses the server actions to make the Discovery results available within WA. I am going to post more later as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of options to link up a IBM Watson Assistant chatbot to IBM Watson Discovery.

1. The first and oldest is to have the application interact with Watson Assistant and, depending on the flow, context and response send a request to Watson Discovery. Basically, the integration is done in the application layer.
2. The second option is to use [server or client dialog actions](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-actions#dialog-actions) in Assistant to directly call into Discovery. See my blog on a [barebone news chatbot](https://blog.4loeser.net/2018/11/ibm-cloud-5-minute-barebone-news-chatbot.html) and the [related code on GitHub](https://github.com/data-henrik/watson-chatbot-discovery-news) on how to implement such an action. My example uses client actions (basically let the app handle it again), but server actions are similar. This [IBM Cloud solution tutorial covers server actions for a database-driven bot](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-slack-chatbot-database-watson#build-a-database-driven-slackbot).
3. The newest option and currently in beta is to use the direct integration of Assistant and Discovery. See "[Building a search skill](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-skill-search-add#skill-search-add)" for an introduction into this direct linkage between IBM Watson Assistant and IBM Watson Discovery.

The option 2 (server action) and 3 should work from the "Try it" in the tooling, the others not because of the app-based coordination.

As usual in IT, there are different way to achieve the goal, the choice is yours... ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the help.